# Solving for an input value of an R function

Tags: r, function, optimization, mathematical-optimization, algebra

In my attached R function, I was wondering how to solve for `mdes` (suppose it is unknown) which is currently one of the input values IF everything else is known?

Is it also possible to solve for `mdes` and `power` (both currently input values) IF everything else is known?

```
foo <- function(A = 200, As = 15, B = 100,Bs = 10,iccmax = 0.15,mdes = .25,SD = 1.2,power = 80)
{
  tail <- 2
  alpha <- 5
  inv_d <- function(mdes) {
    c(mean_dif = 1, Vmax = 2/mdes^2)
  }
  SDr <- 1/SD
  pars <- inv_d(mdes)
  mean_dif <- pars[[1]]
  Vmax <- pars[[2]]
  zbeta <- qnorm((power/100))
  zalpha <- qnorm(1-(alpha/(100*tail)))
  maxvarmean_difhat <- (mean_dif / (zbeta + zalpha))**2
  ntreat <- sqrt((A/As)*((1-iccmax)/iccmax))
  ncont <- sqrt((B/Bs)*((1-iccmax)/iccmax))
  costpertreatcluster <- A + (As*ntreat)
  costperconcluster <- B + (Bs*ncont)
  gtreat <- (sqrt(A*iccmax) + sqrt(As*(1-iccmax)))**2
  gcon <- (sqrt(B*iccmax) + sqrt(Bs*(1-iccmax)))**2
  pratio <- sqrt(gtreat/gcon)
  budgetratio <- 99999
  budgetratio <- ifelse( ((pratio <= SD) & (pratio >= SDr)), pratio**2, ifelse((pratio > SD), pratio*SD, pratio*SDr))
  fraction <- budgetratio/(1 + budgetratio)
  mmvnumer <- 99999
  mmvnumer <- ifelse( ((pratio <= SD) & (pratio >= SDr)),
                      gcon*Vmax*(1+(pratio**2)),
                      ifelse((pratio > SD),
                             gcon*Vmax*(((pratio*SD)+1)**2/((SD**2)+1)),
                             gcon*Vmax*(((pratio*SDr)+1)**2/((SDr**2) + 1))) )
  budget <- mmvnumer/maxvarmean_difhat
  treatbudget <- fraction*budget
  conbudget <- (1-fraction)*budget
  ktreat <- treatbudget/costpertreatcluster
  kcont <- conbudget/costperconcluster
  ktreatrup <- ceiling(ktreat)
  kcontrup <- ceiling(kcont)
  ktreatplus <- ifelse(pmin(ktreatrup,kcontrup) < 8, ktreatrup + 3, ktreatrup + 2)
  kcontplus <- ifelse(pmin(ktreatrup,kcontrup) < 8, kcontrup + 3, kcontrup + 2)
  budgetplus <- (ktreatplus*costpertreatcluster) + (kcontplus*costperconcluster)
  
  return(c(ncont = ncont, kcont = kcontplus,
    ntreat = ntreat, ktreat = ktreatplus, budget = budgetplus))
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo()

       ncont        kcont       ntreat       ktreat       budget 
    7.527727    73.000000     8.692270    62.000000 33279.051347
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function of one variable as

```
p0 = foo()
fn1 = function(x) sum((foo(mdes=x) - p0)^2)
```

and find a minimum that should be 0, and which corresponds to your `mdes = 0.25` input!

```
optimize(fn1, c(0.0, 1.0))
## $minimum
## [1] 0.2497695
## $objective
## [1] 0
```

For two variables, this is more difficult, as the function has many local minima and is ill-defined outside certain regions. Applying `optim()` you will need well-chosen starting points.

Comment: Also, it seems if we change the interval to say `c(-15, 15)` in your your `optimize()` call, the answer changes, could we replace `optimize()` with `uniroot()`?

Comment: No. `uniroot` requires the function to change sign in the interval. The function here is positive everywhere by definition.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind taking a look at [this follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634808/optimization-solve-for-an-input-value-given-a-known-output-value-in-r)?