# Optimization: Solve for an input value given a known output value in R

Tags: r, function, math, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I know I can do:

```
p0 = foo()  ;  fn1 = function(x) sum((foo(power=x) - p0)^2) 
optimize(fn1, c(0, 100))[[1]] ### >[1] 79.8817 almost 80 as `power` in input of `foo()`
```

to solve for `power` (suppose it was unknown) which is currently one of the input values in my below function (`foo`).

**Question:** But now suppose I know one of the OUTPUTS (`budget`) of `foo`, can I now solve back for `power` (which is one of the inputs) via optimization?

```
foo <- function(A = 200, As = 15, B = 100,Bs = 10, power = 80, iccmax = 0.15,mdes = .25,SD = 1.2)
{
  tail <- 2
  alpha <- 5
  inv_d <- function(mdes) {
    c(mean_dif = 1, Vmax = 2/mdes^2)
  }
  SDr <- 1/SD
  pars <- inv_d(mdes)
  mean_dif <- pars[[1]]
  Vmax <- pars[[2]]
  zbeta <- qnorm((power/100))
  zalpha <- qnorm(1-(alpha/(100*tail)))
  maxvarmean_difhat <- (mean_dif / (zbeta + zalpha))**2
  ntreat <- sqrt((A/As)*((1-iccmax)/iccmax))
  ncont <- sqrt((B/Bs)*((1-iccmax)/iccmax))
  costpertreatcluster <- A + (As*ntreat)
  costperconcluster <- B + (Bs*ncont)
  gtreat <- (sqrt(A*iccmax) + sqrt(As*(1-iccmax)))**2
  gcon <- (sqrt(B*iccmax) + sqrt(Bs*(1-iccmax)))**2
  pratio <- sqrt(gtreat/gcon)
  budgetratio <- 99999
  budgetratio <- ifelse( ((pratio <= SD) & (pratio >= SDr)), pratio**2, ifelse((pratio > SD), pratio*SD, pratio*SDr))
  fraction <- budgetratio/(1 + budgetratio)
  mmvnumer <- 99999
  mmvnumer <- ifelse( ((pratio <= SD) & (pratio >= SDr)),
                      gcon*Vmax*(1+(pratio**2)),
                      ifelse((pratio > SD),
                             gcon*Vmax*(((pratio*SD)+1)**2/((SD**2)+1)),
                             gcon*Vmax*(((pratio*SDr)+1)**2/((SDr**2) + 1))) )
  budget <- mmvnumer/maxvarmean_difhat
  treatbudget <- fraction*budget
  conbudget <- (1-fraction)*budget
  ktreat <- treatbudget/costpertreatcluster
  kcont <- conbudget/costperconcluster
  ktreatrup <- ceiling(ktreat)
  kcontrup <- ceiling(kcont)
  ktreatplus <- ifelse(pmin(ktreatrup,kcontrup) < 8, ktreatrup + 3, ktreatrup + 2)
  kcontplus <- ifelse(pmin(ktreatrup,kcontrup) < 8, kcontrup + 3, kcontrup + 2)
  budgetplus <- (ktreatplus*costpertreatcluster) + (kcontplus*costperconcluster)
  
  return(c(ncont = ncont, kcont = kcontplus,
    ntreat = ntreat, ktreat = ktreatplus, budget = budgetplus))
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo()

       ncont        kcont       ntreat       ktreat       budget 
    7.527727    73.000000     8.692270    62.000000 33279.051347
```

Comment: What did you mean: Keeping all inputs except `power` constant? Then of course you can do that, even with applying `uniroot`. If you want to vary all inputs to reconstruct just one output, this will very likely not be possible because of all the local minima (and also because of the many NAs your function produces).

Comment: Suppose I know one of outputs, `budget`, can that help determine one of the input values that might be unknown like `power` or `mdes`? And yes keeping everything else constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought you could do this yourself, easily.

```
b0 = foo()[5]               # budget: 33279.051347
fn2 = function(x) {
    foo(power = x)["budget"] - b0
}
uniroot(fn2, c(70, 90))
## $root
## [1] 79.99041
## $f.root
## budget 
##      0
```

This may not work for all input variables, depending on how much influence they have on the different outputs.